# Export SOAPUI Test Suite to Parasoft

Tags: soapui, soa, parasoft

Right now i am using SOAPUI to run xml request and verifying response.

Now i want to move all test suite to parasoft, so that i can run my test using parasoft.

Is there any way to import all to parasoft at once ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

- SoapUI exports the test suite in xml format which confirms to its own schema.
- The above exported format may not be useful to Parasoft. Novoice in parasoft though.
- However, SoapUI provides multiple ways to execute the test cases which I believe could be useful to you.
  -- command line utility: SOAPUI_HOME/bin/testrunner.bat(.sh) can execute the test suites. Please find more details about the utility options from [documentation](https://www.soapui.org/test-automation/running-from-command-line/functional-tests.html)
  -- Java API : It is possible to execute the projects using SOAPUI's API. Also execute like a junit test. Refer [documentation](https://www.soapui.org/test-automation/junit/junit-integration.html) for the same.

Hope this is useful.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct migration script that converts SOAPUI to Parasoft SOATest.. but your use your request XML from SOAPUI to create request in literal SOATest

Comment: I found a github project for converting soapui to Parasoft soatest , you can try your luck https://github.com/a2vplugin/SoapUIToSOAtestPlugin